# First Name property is not being defined in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

In my .cshtml.cs file I have this:

```
using CubeAuthAttempt1.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace CubeAuthAttempt1.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class CubeInfoModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        //constructor 
        public CubeInfoModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async void Load(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            ViewData["firstname"] = user.FirstName; 
        }
    }
}
```

In its .cshtml file I'm having this:

```
@page
@model CubeAuthAttempt1.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.CubeInfoModel



<div>
    <h2>Welcome @ViewData["firstname"]</h2>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with ViewData or if I'm just not using UserManager correctly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue you are facing? Is it that you are not able to see any value in your view against "firstname"?

Comment: Use the debugging tool, to check if user.FirstName even has a value at all. If it does, then see if ViewData["firstname"] also gets that very same value.